# Uncaught TypeError: contract.name is not a function

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, ganache, truffle-migration

I`m trying to check if I correctly deploy a contract with truffle and ganache.
I run `truffle console` and then `contract = await Kryptobird.deployed()`. But when I try to get the name of the contract I have this error

```
truffle(development)> contract.name()
evalmachine.<anonymous>:0
contract.name()
         ^

Uncaught TypeError: contract.name is not a function
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>
    at sigintHandlersWrap (node:vm:268:12)
    at Script.runInContext (node:vm:137:14)
    at runScript (C:\Users\Марія\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\console.js:364:1)
    at Console.interpret (C:\Users\Марія\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\console.js:379:1)
    at bound (node:domain:421:15)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (node:domain:432:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (node:repl:889:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at REPLServer.emit (node:domain:475:12)
```

The code of the contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract Kryptobird{

    string private name;
    string private symbol;

    constructor() {

        name = 'Kryptobirdz';
        symbol = 'KBIRDZ';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string private name;
```

It is explicitly set to *private* visibility which means that it is not visible ... meaning there is no `name()` function.

There would be a function generated approximately like this if the visibility was `public`:

```
function name() public view returns(string memory) {
  return name;
}
```

But it is not, so no function.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep, all is work now!

Answer (score 0):

The solution code is

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract Kryptobird{

    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;

    constructor() {

        _name = 'Kryptobirdz';
        _symbol = 'KBIRDZ';
    }

    function name() public view returns(string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public view returns(string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

}
```

Comment: It will be nice if you could add a small explanation about your solution.